# Highlight selected text from JSONPath using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, json, xpath, jsonpath

I am using [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to select some elements from a JSON file. I want the selected elements to be displayed on an html page. (The entire JSON should be displayed with only the selected tags highlighted)

The final result should look like the 
[XPath Evaluator](http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator) in the Defient.js site.

So far, I've managed to use the JSONPath to select the element I want and get it as the output. Also, I can use `JSON.stringify` in a `<pre>` tag to print the JSON to the webpage.

What I want to know is how I should go about highlighting the selected text. The output can't be simply used to generate a regex because it might match fields that are not selected by the JSONPath filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've told that you can get the path, it'll be just matter of wrapping the value for the corresponding path with a html tag and give a class. Then you can highlight with css.

```css
pre {
   background-color: ghostwhite;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   margin: 20px; 
   }
.json-key {
   color: brown;
   }
.json-value {
   color: navy;
   }
.json-string {
   color: olive;
   }
```

```html
    <pre><code id="planets">[
       {
          <span class="json-key">name</span>: <span class="json-string">"Earth"</span>,
          <span class="json-key">order</span>: <span class="json-value">3</span>,
          <span class="json-key">stats</span>: {
             <span class="json-key">life</span>: <span class="json-value">true</span>,
             <span class="json-key">mass</span>: <span class="json-value">5.973600000000001e+24</span>
          }
       },
       {
          <span class="json-key">name</span>: <span class="json-string">"Saturn"</span>,
          <span class="json-key">order</span>: <span class="json-value">6</span>,
          <span class="json-key">stats</span>: {
             <span class="json-key">life</span>: <span class="json-value">null</span>,
             <span class="json-key">mass</span>: <span class="json-value">5.6846e+26</span>
          }
       }
    ]</code></pre>
```

[Example replacer](http://jsfiddle.net/526ovnv7/) - but not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question I have left is how am I supposed to print the JSON file into HTML?

Comment: @nipuna777 right, that's basically depends on how you get the file, could you tell me how are you supposed to do that? It should probably from the server right.

Comment: I'm currently reading from a local file(JSON) in to a JavaScript object. It is prettymuch the same as getting it from a a server.

Comment: @nipuna777 right, if you want to read *local* files from browser and your browser is HTML5 compatible, take a look on [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). But, still, there is no guarantee that every browser supports it as it's [no longer part of the w3c standard](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). The ultimate and recommended way is to make a request (may be ajax) to the server to get the data and render it.